# Up (with) the workers!

Tags: register, dialect, interjections

Here are a few questions about expressions like:

> Up (with) the workers!"

1. Are they old-fashioned?
2. Do they mean the same as "Viva . . ."? Could we say, e.g., "Viva the workers!"?
3. Should the preposition "with" be dropped? Is there dialectal variation in this regard?

Comment: Dropping 'with' could change the meaning to an insult, as in "up yours!"

Comment: We don't use 'viva' much in BrE, perhaps in southern US with more Spanish influence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Up the workers!* sounds much more powerful and dynamic to me. It's meant to be a punchy slogan or exclamation, and the grammar is a little similar to newspaper headline styles, where you omit words to make it short and snappy.

There's a common joke about protest groups who aren't very good at it, where they're shown using excessively wordy or pedantically correct chants, which end up having no energy - and the point of a chant is to get people fired up! *Up **with** the workers* isn't *too* bad, but it sounds a little formal and polite - but it really depends on the chant, if there's a powerful rhythm to it, like **UP. WITH. THE WORKERS!** it might sound better. It really depends!

As for old fashioned... in the UK, if a crowd at a football match was shouting *UP THE REDS* it might sound a little dated to my ears, yeah. *Up the [something]* sounds old-fashioned, compared to something like *COME ON YOU BLUES* or whatever.

But I'd say it's a little different when you're talking about political chants, especially for long-established concepts like working-class solidarity, comradeship and so on. That's a lot less about sounding cool and more about tapping into important ideas and strength, and trying to project some power. So the meaning of the language is much more than just whether it sounds cool and modern, if that makes sense. Sounding dated isn't something anyone is going to worry about, so long as it's working!